# how to get data from $http.post in controller

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am using AngularJS and codeigniter. Here I want to pass my `emp_id` from AngularJS controller  to codeigniter controller.

Here I am using `$http.post` for passing my id to php. But I didn't get any id in php controller . I have tried other `$http` methods also, but I couldn't.

**Angular js controller**

```
angular.module('Myapp').controller('MYcntroller', function ($rootScope,  $scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { 
        App.initAjax(); // initialize core components
        Layout.setSidebarMenuActiveLink('set', $('#sidebar_menu_link_empmng'));  // set profile link active in sidebar menu 
    });

    // set sidebar closed and body solid layout mode
    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = true;
    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = false;

    var emp_id = 100;

    $http.post(base_url+"CI_controller/getData", {'emp_id': emp_id})
    .success(function (response) {
        // alert(response)
        $scope.data = response.data
    });

});
```

**Php controller**

```
public function getData() {
    //here $emp_id is null why?
    $emp_id = $this->input->post('emp_id');
    $emp_data=$this->model->employee_details($emp_id );
    echo '{"data":'.json_encode($emp_data).'}';
}
```

Comment: try `$this->post('emp_id')` instead of `$this->input->post('emp_id')`

Comment: Try to set the http header as `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: @FernandoZamperin in angular the default  content-type is application/json only.

Answer (score 0):

use the http post like this.

```
$http.post(base_url+"CI_controller/getData", {"emp_id": emp_id})
    .success(function (response) {
        // alert(response)
        $scope.data = response.data
    });
```

since JSON Object keys must be strings (i.e. a character sequence enclosed in double quotes ").

Comment: @rogernm, try this `$emp_id = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);` with this you can read the body of the post request in php as an array, i don't have any more ideas it must be some config problem inside your codeigniter

Comment: i don't know why it happens. Is any other idea/

Comment: can you check if the controller  is actually hit by the angular post call?